# DropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged event calls all events

Tags: asp.net, webforms

i'm using  Asp .Net Web Forms. i have 2 dropDown list and 1 input field. I want when i change the item on the dropDown list or the field value to call some event but it calls all the events.

for example if i change size it calls Size_SelectedIndexChanged, then Color_SelectedIndexChanged, and then txtKolicina_TextChanged
if i change color it calls Color_SelectedIndexChanged, than Size_SelectedIndexChanged and then txtKolicina_TextChanged.

Any help?

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="Colors" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control detal-page-input" Style="height: 30px;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Colors_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource3" DataTextField="color" DataValueField="color" >
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="Size" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Size_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control detal-page-input" Style="height: 30px;" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource2" DataTextField="size" DataValueField="size" EnableViewState="true">
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>


     <asp:TextBox Name="txtKolicina" ID="txtKolicina" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-numberone detal-page-input" OnTextChanged="txtKolicina_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
```

this is backEnd

```
   protected void Size_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//do something
}
    protected void Colors_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//do something
}
 protected void txtKolicina_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
//do something
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
public string[] GetColor()
{
    CMS_Shop_ModuleDataContext db = new CMS_Shop_ModuleDataContext();
    var color = (from p in db.CMS_Articles
        where
            p.articleID == int.Parse(HiddenFieldArticalId.Value) ||
            p.sameAsArticleID == int.Parse(HiddenFieldArticalId.Value)
        //where p.articleID == 10049 || p.sameAsArticleID == 10049
        select p.color).Distinct();
    return color.ToArray();
}
public int GetColorCount()
{
    CMS_Shop_ModuleDataContext db = new CMS_Shop_ModuleDataContext();
    var color = (from p in db.CMS_Articles
        where (p.articleID == int.Parse(HiddenFieldArticalId.Value)
               || p.sameAsArticleID == int.Parse(HiddenFieldArticalId.Value))
              && p.color != ""
        select p.color);

    return color.Distinct().Count();

}
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
 if (GetColorCount() == 0)
        {

            Colors.Visible = false;
            lblBoja.Visible = false;

        }
        else
        {
            Colors.Visible = true;
            lblBoja.Visible = true;



        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found what was the problem.
a change

EnableViewState="false"

to

```
  EnableViewState="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use View State and repopulate your DropDownLists in code behind on Postback. Can you show OnInit and OnLoad ?

Or just try this code:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    // populate all drop downs lists
}
```

Comment: Can you show the rest part of the Page_Load? 
What comes in the else block of if (!Page.IsPostBack)?